# Ubuntu 16.04 is very sluggish

Tags: 16.04

I'm an Ubuntu newbie and just installed Ubuntu on a secondary SSD today. I managed to get everything working and I have booted into the Ubuntu desktop, however, everything is really really sluggish. It takes about 0.5 seconds for a letter to appear after I type, and the same for clicking on things. My system is relatively powerful so I'm fairly sure specs aren't the issue. 
Skylake i5 laptop processor (cant remember exact name)
GTX 960m with 4gb vram
8gb ram
And dual ssds
Please help me ;(

Comment: Who made your computer, and what's the model number of it?

Comment: Skylake CPUs require special Grub parameters for optimal performance and the Nvidia GTX960m definitely benefits from proprietary drivers.

Comment: Some Skylake integrated GPUs are not too well supported by the Linux kernel. Could it be that your system is running in some kind of low-graphics mode/software rendering because it tries to use the Intel GPU and fails? Try `sudo apt install inxi` to install a little sysinfo tool and then show us the output of `inxi -G` describing your graphics setup.